# Keycloak 1.9.4 using custom federation running out off memory

Tags: java, keycloak

I am using Keycloak 1.9.4 as a Single Sign On solution running on a Windows 64 bit server using a custom user federation that connects to remote databases containing user credentials. While it functionally works, when trialled with a large number of users, the entire heap is exhausted and CPU rises to the point that the Keycloak solution is unresponsive and the server log has multiple lines like this logged

*XNIO001007: A channel event listener threw an exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded*

The heap has been expanded to 2GB, has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Have you analysed the dump to see if you find many instances of one particular class?

Comment: Yes, I have. It turns out the bulk of the heap had been consumed with references to org.xnio.nio.XnioWorker. Internet searches revealed there has been an issue with underlying SSL management of Keycloak. To get round this, we have installed Apache 2.2 as a proxy and are using this application to handle SSL requests.